# Comparing integer numbers predicate to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, long-integer

I have this simple query where I need to identify all tickets within start and end number of a specific TicketBook object on api side in EF Core.

```
var ticketBook = await Context.TicketBooks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == query.TicketBookId);
if (ticketBook != null)
{
      dbTickets = dbTickets.Where(x => ConvertTicketNumberToInt(x, ticketBook));
}

private bool ConvertTicketNumberToInt(Ticket t, TicketBook tb)
{
        try
        {
            var numberOnly = new string(t.Number.Where(t => char.IsDigit(t)).ToArray());
            var tNumber = Convert.ToInt64(numberOnly);
            return tNumber >= tb.StartIntNumber && tNumber <= tb.EndIntNumber;
        }
        catch(OverflowException)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

the problem is the "Number" property in Ticket class is nvarchar (string) but I need to convert it into integer for this particular query only and for that I have written a small method which does it for me. But as you can see its very time consuming and not efficient at all so my api call just times out.

I am trying to figure out how to do this in LINQ without writing extra methods like this. The trick is that "number" property can sometimes can have a few alphabets in it which throws exception while converting it to integer so I need to remove those non digit characters before the comparison that's why I had to write this dedicated method for it.

Comment: Why you store strings if it's actually a long? You could have another column which stores that int value if available.

Comment: Have you looked at the `SqlFunctions` class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions)

Comment: Isnt there anything common between Ticketbooks and Tickets? i.e. some kind of foreign key where you have a booking id in the tickets table which suggests that that ticket(s) are part of a specific booking?

Comment: @TimSchmelter its complicated, it will mostly be a number but on rare ocassions it will be marked with an alphabet at the end so we had to keep it as a string in database. yes we could have another column but that would be a huge change for our architecture right now which is not possible for me to do right now.

Comment: @shahkalpeshp Unfortunately no, there is no direct foreign key or any id there at the moment, only way is to query ticket number between start and end number of a ticket book.

Comment: @MuhammadTouseef: Still it doesn't explain why you don't have two columns, one which stores the original string and one which stores the int-value. Use a stored-procedure to extract the value on insert/update.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ideally we should have a 2nd column I agree with you, I am just trying to find a work around right now which can be a quicker solution as a 2nd column raising other concerns we already have a lot of data in database. and lot of logic to go through if e add another column right now.

Comment: I was going to suggest doing this at backend. I suspect, it will still take time unless there is some index to support. Also, what does `t.Number` look like that you have to check every char to be a digit. If it is ABC1234, you could extract string from 4th char (at backend) to filter records. Also, how many records do you expect user to query? You could limit the number of records. Otherwise, this will need to scan the entire table to find the matches.

Comment: yeah the letter will be right at end of the string, so maybe I should check with if condition if there is a letter at the end then just remove the last character and then convert to long? @shahkalpeshp

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you are facing some performance issues storing `nvarchar` instead of long.

Anyway, what you're doing in your code is not that bad - you have fairly simple method for the job which keeps your LINQ code clean and tidy. But since you want to have a single LINQ query, try the following (it can be done shorter but I've chosen this way for readability):

```
var ticketBook = await Context.TicketBooks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == query.TicketBookId);
if (ticketBook != null)
{
    dbTickets = dbTickets
        .Select(t => new { Ticket = t, Number = new string(t.Number.Where(n => char.IsDigit(n)).ToArray()) })
        .Select(t => 
        {
            long ticketNumber = long.MinValue;
            long.TryParse(t.Number), out ticketNumber);
            return new { Ticket = t, Number = ticketNumber };
        })
        .Where(t => t.Ticket >= ticketBook.StartIntNumber && t.Ticket <= ticketBook.EndIntNumber)
        .Select(t => t.Ticket);
}
```

What it does:

- in first pass all your `varchars` are stripped of the letters and converted to strings containing only the digits, then an anonymous type with the complete `Ticket` class is returned along with this string
- the strings are parsed to long - I've abused `long.MinValue` to indicate a  failed conversion (since you're using `char.IsDigit(c)` I see you're not expect any negative values in your results. You might as well use `ulong` for twice the positive range and abuse 0 value) and again, an anonymous type is returned
- those anonymous structures are filtered with the condition you provided
- finally, only the original `Ticket` structure is returned

If you're concerned about the number of passes over the initial results - I've run several performance tests to find out whether having a number of `Select`s with short operations inside is slower than having one pass with an elaborate operation and I haven't observed any significant difference.

Comment: I've just read your comment saying that there is possibly only one letter in the `Number` and it's always at the end of the string. In this case you can have the first Select as `.Select(t => new { Ticket = t, Number = char.IsDigit(t.Number.Last()) ? t.Number : t.Number.Substring(0, t.Number.Length - 1) })` - saves you creating a new string if there isn't any letter at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do most of the conversion in the database.

If you have access to the context, you can do this:

```
dbTickets = Context.Tickets
  .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Number) = 0 THEN Number ELSE LEFT(Number,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Number)-1) END as int) BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", ticketBook.StartIntNumber, ticketBook.EndIntNumber)
  .ToList();
```

This will strip off any trailing letters from the Number column and convert it to an int, then use that to make sure it is between your StartIntNumber and EndIntNumber.

That said, I would highly suggest you add an additional column into your tickets table that uses a derivative of the above to calculate an integer and then make the column a persistent calculated column.  Then you can index on that column.  Very little (if ANY) should need to be changed in your code if you do this, and the performance benefit will be huge.

This is based on your comment that said sometimes Number has additional letters at the end, like 123A.  The above would need to be modified if Number can have letters at the start or in the middle like A123 or 1A23.  Currently, it would treat A123 as 0, and 1A23 as 1.